# How to use different font face for different languages?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have developed my web app which supports English and Japanese. I have different font-face in English. Recently i got requirement like different font face for Japanese for some elements such as h1, h2, p.

font names are already written for many elements. So i cannot go and change for each elements. Suggest me to handle this situation.

I can add class to body as "lang-eng" or "lang-ja" as per language.

English:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "DroidSerif";
 src: url("https://rawgit.com/google/fonts/master/ufl/ubuntumono/UbuntuMono-Italic.ttf")
format("truetype");
}
```

Japanese :

```
@font-face {
font-family: "DroidSerif";
 src: url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/ea/notosansjp/v5/NotoSansJP-
 Regular.woff2")
    format("truetype");
```

}

Is it possible to use same font-face name and different src ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: CSS is not a programming language, and I think that it is not possible to detect language using it.

Comment: @SaidbakR Its not about detecting language. I can set the class as per language to the body. I need to apply different font styles according to class name without changing font-face name since not ready to touch all the css code.

Comment: I like Kobys idea, allthough I would leave it all in one css file and just add / remove classes which then have the different styling. For example: add a class ".japanese" to all your elements that have a different styling in japanese mode, and use the other font in your css on all elements with the class japanese

Comment: @TimGerhard. Since its ssr i can't ask backend team to do those stuffs. I have only one style.css where i have all code.

Comment: _“I can add class to body as "lang-eng" or "lang-ja" as per language”_ - don’t - that’s what the `lang` attribute is for to begin with.

Answer (score 15):

You can specify the subset of characters that each font family `src` should be used with, [as explained here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/webfont-optimization?hl=es-419). Your example would look like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "DroidSerif";
  src: url("https://rawgit.com/google/fonts/master/ufl/ubuntumono/UbuntuMono-Italic.ttf")
  format("truetype");
  unicode-range: U+000-5FF; /* Latin glyphs */
}


@font-face {
  font-family: "DroidSerif";
  src: url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/ea/notosansjp/v5/NotoSansJP-Regular.woff2")
  format("truetype");
  unicode-range: U+3000-9FFF, U+ff??; /* Japanese glyphs */
}
```

Comment: Didn't know that was a thing! +1

Comment: @miguel. It means the element contains Japanese character will get new font family completely?

Comment: It will, for the characters in the range specified. Check it: https://codepen.io/miguelcalderon/pen/qoPJNy

Comment: Empty squares may be rendered if the font has not some glyphs for the specified range.

Comment: Of course, you should make sure that you're using a font that includes the glyphs you will be using.

Comment: "You should make sure that you're using a font that includes the glyphs you will be using" - I dint get this point. and in some places i may have combination of English and Ja. So this will also be taken care is it ?

Comment: Yes, as long as you're using glyphs (≈characters) that are included in the font file for the subset. So yes, you can mix languages.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `font-family` name value to be something like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "DroidSerifEng";
 src: url("https://rawgit.com/google/fonts/master/ufl/ubuntumono/UbuntuMono-Italic.ttf")
format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
font-family: "DroidSerifJap";
 src: url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/ea/notosansjp/v5/NotoSansJP-
 Regular.woff2")
    format("truetype");
}
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.lang-eng{
 font-family: DroidSerifEng !important;
}

.lang-ja{
 font-family: DroidSerifJap !important;
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<body class="lang-eng"> English
```

and

```
<body class="lang-ja"> Japanese
```

Comment: For English i have used 11 font-families which contains bold, italic, regular and light, So I can't replace all font family as a single one for Japanese. Japanese also have many font faces. Thanks